# output stream operator's overload

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Why does the output stream operator's overload works with this prototype:

```
ostream &operator<<(ostream &flux, Complexe const & z);
```

and doesn't go with this one

```
ostream operator<<(ostream &flux, Complexe const & z);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can declare an `operator<<` that returns `ostream` by value but you might have trouble defining it! `ostream` has a deleted copy constructor and a protected move constructor.

Comment: Moving is [technically possible](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/basic_ostream). Also, the moved-from state might set `badbit`, so things could work out somehow.

Comment: Sure, I guess you could use `std::move`, but it's clearly wrong to do so because the argument must have been an lvalue in the first place.

Comment: That's not the point. You say one can't move from the lvalue argument, though actually one can. (I agree that doing that is badly wrong!) Also, the argument could have been a rvalue of class type that provides a conversion operator to `ostream&`, but enough nitpickerity today :o)

Comment: I think the issue in returning `std::move(flux)` is that in doing `cout << z << 3;` you end up moving the stream to a temporary (`cout << z`), which is then destroyed at the end of the expression, and leave the stream in an unusable state. Isn't it?

Comment: @Columbo Actually I just noticed the move constructor is protected.

Comment: @Brian Oh... weird. That doesn't make sense to me at all. Unless they wan't to encapsulate the base class interface. Well, mea culpa, keep the answer as is. :)

Comment: Yes indeed, it looks like `basic_ostream<>` has protected ctors. Only derived classes like `basic_ofstream<>` seem to have move semantics enabled.

Comment: @Columbo I think it makes sense. Presumably, it's intended that the only objects of complete type `basic_ostream` are the standard streams, *i.e.*, `cout`, `cerr`, `clog` and their wide character cousins, and there's no reason why you should ever want to move those.

Comment: @Brian No, that is definitely *not* inteded. I often create my own stream buffer class and initialize a most-derived object of type `ostream` with that.

Comment: @Columbo Oh whoops, I forgot there was *another* constructor. Damn, today is not my day.

Comment: @Columbo They are protected because they have very weird semantics (they move everything except `rdbuf()`); and they have very weird semantics because in a derived class `rdbuf()` can point inside the stream object itself (which is usually how fstreams etc. are implemented).